# How to extract certain rows in a table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the following table (df):

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | finished | 1234 |
| A2 | ongoing | 1235 |
| A3 | NaN | 1236 |
| A4 | finished | 1237 |
| A5 | started | 1238 |
| A6 | finished | 1239 |

I would like to extract the rows that are not finished. How do I do that?

**Desired output:**

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | ongoing | 1235 |
| A3 | NaN | 1236 |
| A5 | started | 1238 |

What I tried so far?

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data="""
col1    col2    col3
A1  finished    1234
A2  ongoing 1235
A3  NaN 1236
A4  finished    1237
A5  started 1238
A6  finished    1239
"""

data_tsv = StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(data_tsv, sep="\t", skiprows=1)

tab_not_finished = df[df['col2'] != 'finished']
print(tab_not_finished)
```

This does not extract the row that contains NaN. How do I include NaNs?

Comment: `df[~(df['col2'] == 'finished')]`

Comment: For me working correct your solution.

Comment: Thanks, that wors!

Comment: @jezrael - you are right.

Comment: If not working maybe is necessary upgrade pandas.

Comment: Alternatively `df2.query('Col2 != "finished"')`

Answer (score 0):

On pandas 1.3.1, your code works:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>> df[df['col2'] != 'finished']
  col1     col2  col3
2   A2  ongoing  1235
3   A3      NaN  1236
5   A5  started  1238
```

Alternately, as answered in the comments, you can negate the equality comparison

```
>>> df[~(df['col2'] == 'finished')]
  col1     col2  col3
2   A2  ongoing  1235
3   A3      NaN  1236
5   A5  started  1238
```